# getting error as MIME type ('') is not executable in servlet web application deployed in apache karaf

Tags: javascript, angular, servlets, apache-karaf

I try to load the js files in the jsp page of servlet web application in the apache karaf.

the project structure is shown in the image link [project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y0hQi.jpg)

js files includes angular.min.js, angular.route.min.js files are loaded but welcome.js file which is angular controller file is not loading.
the sample code is as below

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/resources/js/angular-cookies.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/resources/js/spin.min.js"></script>
```

But the below js file is not loading

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/resources/js/welcome.js"></script>
```

[error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pw4km.jpg)

getting the error as shown in the above image link.

how to resolve the issue ?

Comment: This is due to cross origin check. Your script tag trying to load files from external server.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Sumesh TG, how can we resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue is solved by handling the resources mapping in the servlet.
I added the following code snippet in my Dashboard servlet.

```
if (request.getServletPath().startsWith("/resources/")){    
        RequestDispatcher rd = getServletContext().getNamedDispatcher("default");
        rd.include(request, response);
  }
```

By adding the above code my issue is resolved.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution 1**

Create a filter like shown below

```
 public class CorsFilter implements Filter{
    
        @Override
        public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response,
        FilterChain filterChain) throws IOException, ServletException {
    
            if(response instanceof HttpServletResponse){
            HttpServletResponse alteredResponse = ((HttpServletResponse)response);
            addCorsHeader(alteredResponse);
        }
    
        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
        }
    
        private void addCorsHeader(HttpServletResponse response){
            //TODO: externalize the Allow-Origin
            response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
            response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE, HEAD");
            response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "X-PINGOTHER, Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
            response.addHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "1728000");
        }
    
        @Override
        public void destroy() {}
    
        @Override
        public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig)throws ServletException{}
    }
```

and include this filter in `web.xml`

```
<filter>
        <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>com.yourpackage.CorsFilter </filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

**Solution 2**

Configure CORS directly in `web.xml`

```
<filter>
        <filter-name>CORS</filter-name>
        <filter-class>com.thetransactioncompany.cors.CORSFilter</filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>cors.allowGenericHttpRequests</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>cors.allowOrigin</param-name>
            <param-value>*</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>cors.allowSubdomains</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>cors.supportedMethods</param-name>
            <param-value>GET, HEAD, POST, DELETE, PUT, OPTIONS</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>cors.supportedHeaders</param-name>
            <param-value>Content-Type, X-Requested-With</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>cors.exposedHeaders</param-name>
            <param-value>X-Test-1, X-Test-2</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>cors.supportsCredentials</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>cors.maxAge</param-name>
            <param-value>-1</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>


    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>CORS</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
```

Reference : http://software.dzhuvinov.com/cors-filter-configuration.html

I hope this will help you.

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply Sumesh TG, I tried with the above two solutions still i am getting the same error as "Refused to execute script from '<URL>' because its MIME type ('') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled." Is there any other way to fix this issue?

Comment: Please find the exact file location throwing that error. May be from angular service call.

Comment: the exact file location is "http://localhost:8181/dashboard/resources/js/welcome.js", this i added in the jsp page of welcome.jsp file in the script tag as <script type="text/javascript" src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/resources/js/welcome.js"></script>.

Comment: Inside that file, there may be an ajax call or service call please check. There may be the difference in datatypes for example,  from server sending JSON data then receiving it as JSONP

Comment: In that js file, i commented the previous code and just added a simple alert("message"), and then tried again, still i am getting the same issue.

Comment: Is that url belongs to webserverice call or resource download?

Comment: this url is resource download only, i am able to download other files like spin.min.js, angular-cookies.min.js. But only this welcome.js file is not loading.

Comment: Try that url manually and clean and build the project. Remove the war file from server deploY again.

Comment: Manually i tried the URL then the js file is not loading, Removed the war file and build and deploy several times but still the same issue. One thing i did not getting is in the same folder only all js files are there, then spin.min.js, angular-cookies.min.js are loading but why custom js file welcome.js is not loading??